# Transitive Actions on Set

Tags: group-theory

I am preparing for test so I am posting some of my many questions, my apologizes if it is considered to many.

I am wondering,

Could we have a transitive action of the group $S_{4}$ acting on the set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$?

What I know is that for there to be a transitive action we would need that for every $s_{1}$ , $s_{2} \in S$, that there exists a g in our group such that $g \star s_{1}=s_{2}$

For this example, to me it seems not possible because $|S_{4}|=4!=24$, but there are seemingly more ways we could order the set?

Is this true? How should I think of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an action is transitive then there is only one orbit. So now use the orbit stabilizer theorem to convince yourself that in such a case $|S|$ should divide the order $|G|$ of the group.

Comment: It would just have to divide , not divide and in fact be same as, to get 1 in the orbit stab thereom?

Comment: @PersonaA it need not be equal if that is what your question is. The size of the stabilizer of an element in the set $S$ will be equal to $|G|$, but that doesn't mean that the size of the set has to be equal.

Comment: So since 5 does not divide 24 there wont be such action?

Comment: @PersonaA yes that is correct.